# UDID / IMEI / ... или как идентифицировать apple-девайс пользователя?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Вечер добрый.

На просторах интернета встретил много информации о том, что вроде Apple запрещает размещение приложений, в коде которых программно определяется UDID девайса пользователя (так же как и IMEI).

Неужели нет никаких других способов идентифицировать аппарат на iOS? :(((

Если да, то подскажите функцию, пожалуйста!

ps. Необходимо чтобы этот идентификатор был постоянным, даже при переустановке приложения.

Comment: Вот официальная документация по этому вопросу: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html Т.е. официально считается, что identifierForVendor уникально идентифицирует девайс.

Comment: Т.е. получается, если приложение официально выложено на appstore, то при каждом скачивании его оттуда с одного и того же девайса, identifierForVendor будет одинаковым?
Он есть у устройств без GSM модуля? (планшеты, с которых нельзя звонить - только wi-fi)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите эту библиотеку
https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/FCUUID

Так же можно еще
https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID

И еще
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456996/how-to-get-the-udid-in-ios-6-and-ios-7

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Ответы-ссылки могут стать недействительными в случае изменения страницы, на которую дана ссылка.

Answer (score 0):

Нативный вариант — использовать `identifierForVendor` и сохранять его в Keychain:

```
- (NSString *)getUniqueDeviceIdentifierAsString {
    NSString *appName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleNameKey];
    NSString *strApplicationUUID = [SSKeychain passwordForService:appName account:@"incoding"];
    if (strApplicationUUID == nil) {
        strApplicationUUID = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
        [SSKeychain setPassword:strApplicationUUID forService:appName account:@"incoding"];
    }
    return strApplicationUUID;
}
```

[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22937460/1520360)

В этом варианте стоит учесть две вещи:

1. Идентификатор сбросится при сбросе настроек в iOS (кнопка **«Стереть контент и настройки»** в настройках) с предварительным удаленим всех приложений разработчика.
2. Этот идентификатор будет разный для приложений, у которых *bundle id* начинается с разных *vendor id* (подробней см. в документации к `identifierForVendor`).